# Converting string to korean encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

I am extracting the data of a korean game (Ragnarok Online) to build up a database for it. I had no problems for years to convert the strings from ISO-8859-1 encoding to EUC-KR encoding in c#.

The function I used to convert the string was this.

```
return Encoding.GetEncoding("EUC-KR").GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(text);
```

Example

```
º»Çï¸§ -> 본헬름
```

Now I encounter some characters not converting correctly and I am not sure why.

The ansi string is converted to

```
Œc¾ç²á -> Oc양꿍
```

which is wrong I assume. I tested a bit with encoding in notepad++ and if I convert the string to Korean (Windows-949 instead of EUC-KR) it shows the correct one.

```
똠양꿍
```

But in C#, if I use Codepage 949 it still converts to the wrong one.
The codepage "Windows-949" is not known in .net framework.

What is the correct encoding for this or is the source string just wrong?

Thank you very much.

/edit: problem solved.
seems like ISO-8859-1 AND EUC-KR were wrong. If I convert from 1252 -> 949 it's fine.

Comment: The real question for me is: where did you get `text` from? For encoding scenarios, I would expect the input to be `byte[]`. If you have parsed `text` somehow *other* than in the correct encoding, it is quite likely that you have already corrupted the value long before it gets anywhere near this code.

Comment: The text is read from a textfile. It really seems that ISO-8859-1 is not the correct encoding for it. With source codepage 1252 and target codepage 949 it works fine.

But it's strange its the first time I encountered such a problem.

Comment: but... why are you even trying ISO-8859-1 / 1252 / 949? You seem to *know* the correct encoding - it is 51949 aka EUC-KR. You should be reading the text file *using that encoding*.

Comment: Well, some come from text files, some from a lua script I can't control the encoding that is passed in nLua. Depends on version of Ragnarok Online.

Comment: shuffling between encodings like this is *not* the way to solve this problem - you are risking silent data loss/corruption. It is unclear what role lua is playing here, but again: all file access to a text file **must** use the right encoding. Otherwise the output *is not defined*. It is not "mostly right" - it is ***not defined***. You cannot decode in the wrong encoding and then fixup later: that initial "decode" step can (and will) simply corrupt the text.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the edit with the answer to your question.  I had data from an old database where the data was stored in a Korean language encoding that was not displaying correctly.

After hours of playing with the code to convert the data to a different encoding, I came across your question.  I did the Code Page 1252 to Code Page 949 conversion, and then I started getting valid Korean words out of the database entries.

My code context is from a .NET forms web application, and I'm including the Page_load function below to provide sample code on how to convert from one encoding to another:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DictionaryConnection"].ToString();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string strSQL = "Select top(100) * from Parts";


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);

        SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Load(sdr);


        sdr.Close();


        StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();


        sbOut.Append("<table border=\"1\">");
        sbOut.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            sbOut.Append("<th>" + dc.ColumnName + "</th>");

        }

        sbOut.Append("</tr>");

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

        sbOut.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            string strOut = "";
            if (dr[dc] != null)
            {
                if (dc.ColumnName=="Part_h")
                {


                    int euckrCodepage = 949;//949;//51949;

                    System.Text.Encoding originalEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);


                    System.Text.Encoding euckr = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(euckrCodepage);
                    StringBuilder sbEncoding= new StringBuilder();


                    sbEncoding.Append("RAW: " + dr[dc].ToString() + "<br />");


                   byte[] rawbytes= originalEncoding.GetBytes(dr[dc].ToString());


                   string s = euckr.GetString(rawbytes);
                    sbEncoding.Append("STRING AS "+euckr.EncodingName+": " + s + "<br />");


                    strOut = sbEncoding.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                strOut = dr[dc].ToString();    
                }

            }

            sbOut.Append("<td>" + strOut + "</td>");

        }

            sbOut.Append("</tr>");
        }

        sbOut.Append("</table>");

    conn.Close();
    lblText.Text = sbOut.ToString();
    }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

The German wiki page on [Codepage 949](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_949) compares EUC-KR and 949 and states

> im Gegensatz zu EUC-KR kann sich das nachfolgende Byte jedoch auch im
>   Bereich von 0x41-0x7A befinden
>
> in contrast to EUC-KR the trailing byte can also be in the range from 0x41
>   to 0x7A

which applies to your case of the 'c' (0x63).

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding.aspx) lists codepage 949 as supported by .Net.